# Why was a small vessel tied to the deck of the USS Oriskany during scuttling?

Tags: naval

The final fate of the USS Oriskany (CV-34) is that it was scuttled as an artificial reef in the Gulf of Mexico. It's a fairly famous dive site.

There are photos of the ship as it sank taken by the United States Navy. What I don't understand is there appears to be a small boat strapped down to the deck of the USS Oriskany. Furthermore there is a box in that boat that is also strapped down.

What is the purpose of this boat? What is the box in the boat?

[image]

Photo Credit: [Public domain image taken from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USS_Oriskany_(CV-34)#/media/File:US_Navy_060517-N-7992K-009_The_ex-Oriskany,_a_decommissioned_aircraft_carrier,_was_sunk_24_miles_off_the_coast_of_Pensacola,_Fla.,_on_May_17_to_form_an_artificial_reef.jpg)

Comment: I saw the TV documentary about this, it contained the  equipment for controlling the detonations. If I can find some text to make a reql answer I'll post it.

Comment: It’s apparently not strapped down, as it did not go down with the ship. In videos you can see it still floating at the edge of the foam from the sinking.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Spencer is correct.  The boat on the flight deck is what housed the remote firing system that initiated the firing train.   We attached nonel ( no electric firing cord ) to the initiation point then ran the nonel through the flight deck to detonating cord which branched to various areas of the ship to the main charges.

Tom is correct that the boat isn't actually strapped down.  It is sitting on a frame.

When the ship sank, the boat was left floating on the surface.

How would I know you may ask?  I was one of the Navy Explosive Ordnance Disposal technicians that set the charges to sink the USS Oriskany.

I wrote a small article about my experience sinking the Oriskany.  It can be viewed [here](https://ptsdanddepression.com/battling-depression-ptsd-my-military-stories-creative-art-therapy-emdr-sessions/syncing-the-uss-risk-in-the)

[image][image][image]

Comment: Was it intentional to tick the *Community Wiki* checkbox? I have ticked it by accident a couple of times before I understood its implications.

Comment: Thanks for your service, and in an usual way thanks for sinking her! Lots of good fishing in the area as a result.